# Hidden Navigationbar and Toolbar on Tap a UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I want to Hidden a Navigationbar and Toolbar when i Tap on a UIImageView and when the NavigationBar and Toolbar is hidden and a tap once again i want it back.

```
@IBOutlet var ToolBar: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet var NavigationBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet var FullPhoto: UIImageView!
```

I have this tried but it doest´n works, when i take the view instead of FullPhoto it goes but the Navigationbar and Toolbar is hidden wenn i tap on the Navigationbar and Toolbar.I would to hidden it when i tap on the UIImageView.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapImage")
FullPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Here wos the Code for Hidden the Navigationbar and Toolbar but i would when tap on it it´s hidden and tap once again it´s comes again.

```
func tapImage () {
    NavigationBar.hidden = true
    ToolBar.hidden = true
}
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: make sure to set FullPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t even need to create outlets for your `navBar` and `tabBar` to achieve this. Create an outlet to your `imageView` as you have done.

```
@IBOutlet var FullPhoto: UIImageView!
```

And then in your `viewDidLoad`

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapImage")
FullPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
FullPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

And then create the tap method and check for the `navigationController` and the `tabBarController`.

```
func tapImage(){
     if navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden == false && tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden == false{
         navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
         tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
     }
     else{
         navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
         tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard for your layout, the best practice would be not using `UIGestureRecognizer`, but use `IBActions` instead. Create `IBActions` (**control + drag**) for those elements that you want to be tapped, and set

```
NavigationBar.hidden = true
ToolBar.hidden = true
```

inside the `IBAction`

Comment: @MichaelDiabolo please mark is as the best answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Thanks i make it with Tap on the ScrollView. When i tap on it the Navigationbar and Toolbar is hidden `hidden == true` and once tap again on the ScrollView i want that Navigationbar and Toolbar comes back `hidden==false`. How can i make that ? Thanks for Help

Comment: I have it   @IBAction func Tapgesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if NavigationBar.hidden == false && ToolBar.hidden == false {
            NavigationBar.hidden = true
            ToolBar.hidden = true

        } else if NavigationBar.hidden == true && ToolBar.hidden == true {
            NavigationBar.hidden = false
            ToolBar.hidden = false
        }}`